# Difference between the two statements

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6

Statement 1:

```
delete from table_a where <condition>
```

Statement 2:

```
delete from table_a where id in (select id from table_a <condition>)
```

An implication is, `<condition>` will select out 0.5 million of tuples.

Will these statements cause different locks? Will the second one be safer (less possibility of deadlock)?

Comment: They are not equivalent if `id` is not unique or nullable.

Answer (score 1):

```sql
delete from table_a where <condition>
delete from table_a where id in (select id from table_a <condition>)
```

It is obvious that the first is better.
Because in the second you repeat the same thing while adding more unuseful requests.
It is not pretty to see in my opinion and in addition it consumes too much time.

it would have been understandable if the two tables were different.
example: `table_a` and `table_b`

```sql
delete from table_a where a_id in (select b_id from table_b <condition>)
```

Answer (score 0):

@Sega is correct providing *ID is unique*.  If ID is not unique,however, then results are likely to be are very different.

- The first statement says to delete all rows that meet a given criteria.
- The second says delete all rows for an ID that have at least 1 row
  matching a given criteria.

See [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=af67560c3e72bb2eda4a9ff7e456788d).